# Preparing code for testing

Tags: javascript, rxjs

If I have a function like this:

```
function batchByTime(obs) {
  return obs.bufferWithTime(300).take(10);
}
```

and I want to test it like this:

```
var onNext = Rx.ReactiveTest.onNext,
  onCompleted = Rx.ReactiveTest.onCompleted,
  subscribe = Rx.ReactiveTest.subscribe;

QUnit.test("hello test", function(assert) {
  var scheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler();
  var samplesObservable = scheduler.createHotObservable(
    onNext(100, 1),
    onNext(200, 2),
    onNext(450, 3),
    onNext(1000, 4),
    onCompleted(1100)
  );

  var results = scheduler.
    startWithTiming(function() {
    return batchByTime(samplesObservable);
  }, 0, 0, 1200);

  var msgs = results.messages;
  assert.equal(msgs[0].toString(), onNext(300, [1, 2]).toString());
  assert.equal(msgs[0].toString(), onNext(600, [3]).toString());
  assert.equal(msgs[0].toString(), onNext(900, [4]).toString());
});
```

I'd expect that to work, but instead I get all the notifications at once, receiving:

```
Expected:   
"OnNext(1,2)@300"

Result:
"OnNext(1,2,3,4)@1100"
```

for each assertion.

I understand that this would work if I pass the TestScheduler `scheduler` to `batchByTime`, and use this scheduler as a parameter in the `bufferWithTime` operator. But doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of testing? Ideally I wouldn't have to modify the original code to test it.

Comment: Why does that defeat the purpose of testing? You should be testing the logic, which should work regardless of the scheduler (barring the schedulers that can't do future scheduling). You can just add the parameter and if it is null, `bufferWithTime` will use the default.

Comment: Indeed, part of making code testable is to write code that does not make assumptions.  In this case your `batchByTime` is making an assumption about what Scheduler to use when calling `bufferWithTime`.  Make it testable by removing the assumption and allowing callers to inject the scheduler they wish to use.

Comment: Indeed, making the code more testable is what makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenters to the original question pointed out, the code should be made more testable by parametrizing it with a possible scheduler, using the default scheduer in `bufferWithTime` if no scheduler is provided.